# get highest count of Enumerable objects in class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here I have the following to act as an example

```
public class Items
    {
        public ICollection<ClassName1> Items1 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ClassName2> Items2 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ClassName3> Items3 { get; set; }
    }
```

class Items contain ICollections of strongly typed classes ClassName1, ClassName2, ClassName3

```
    var items = new Items()
    {
        Items1 = GetItems1(),
        Items2 = GetItems2(),
        Items3 = GetItems3()
    }
```

What I want to do:

```
// Get the count of the highest count in items
```

What is a good method to get the highest count from items?

How could Max() be attained without writing each object individually as listed in the this example?

```
{ items.Items1.Count, items.Items2.Count, items.Items3.Count }.Max()
```

So instead

```
{some kind of iterative process to get .Count() of properties in items}.Max()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're stuck on. Combining the three collections together? Comparing one object against another?

Comment: yes, a comparison to get the highest count between Items1, Items2, or Items3.  The tricky part is reflection doesn't work due to ClassName1, ClassName2, ClassName3 being strongly typed.  Note, this is just an example - what I am working with is much larger.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post with your three classes? Do the three classes have anything in common? How exactly do you want to do the comparison?

Comment: These classes do not have anything in common.  It isn't important what the objects in the classes are.

Comment: So then what are you after, the maximum value from `Items1.Count`, `Items2.Count`, and `Items3.Count`, or are you looking to compare the items within each collection?

Comment: in var items, getting the highest count out of the three

Comment: Alright, so now what are you stuck on? Getting the count of elements from each of the properties, or, once you have three integers representing the count of elements in the three properties, finding the largest?

Comment: The highest count of these items without needed to refer to each item class individually.

Comment: "without needing to refer to each item class individually" could you [edit] your post to elaborate on that? What exactly are you trying to solve? `new []{ items.Items1.Count, items.Items2.Count, items.Items3.Count }.Max()` would solve you problem if you knew which properties you wanted to use at compile time.

Comment: That's the fundamental issue - I don't want to pick/choose these properties individually, but there may not an alternative without strongly typing the properties value.  So either ClassName1, ClassName2, ClassName3 would have to be the exact same class, or each item will need to be compared in an enumerable object to get .Max().

Comment: Instead of reflection, you could also annotate this class or the individual properties, make it `partial` and implement a source generator which will generate a method you can use to get the max count. This then would be much faster and would also work with Native AoT. Of course the initial effort is considerably higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like is that you have an object of some class (`Items`), and you are interested in finding the `.Count` of all the *public properties which implement `IEnumerable`*.

Redefining your example class:

```
class Items
{
    public ICollection<string> A { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> B { get; set; }
    public ICollection<char> C { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; } // property to ignore
}
```

And this is how you make the object, somewhere else in your code:

```
var items = new Items
{
    A = ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
    B = [1,2,3,4,5],
    C = ['a', 'b']
};
```

Now the task is, *without using the property name at compile time*, get the values of each of the properties of the `items` object which implement `IEnumerable` to find the `.Count`, and find the `.Max()` from there.

If you're only after the *number* that is the highest, and not what property that highest count belongs to, do something like this:

```
var highestPropertyCollectionCount = typeof(Items)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    .Select(prop => (IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(items))
    .Max(collection => collection.Cast<object>().Count());
```

1. `typeof(Items)` can be replaced by `items.GetType()` if you don't know the type at compile type
2. You need to use `IEnumerable` rather than `ICollection`. I'm not 100% sure the reason though.

In this example case, `highestPropertyCollectionCount` will be "5" (the count of the items in `B`).

If you're only interested in which *property* has the most elements, and not what the count of the collection is, you can do an alteration after the `Where`

```
var propertyWithMostElements = typeof(Items)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable)))
    .OrderByDescending(prop => ((IEnumerable)prop.GetValue(items)).Cast<object>().Count())
    .First();
```

`propertyWithMostElements` would be the `PropertyInfo` for `B`.

Comment: One downside of checking for type IEnumerable is that this will for example also include properties of type string or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to find all the properties of the class that are of type `ICollection<T>` for any `T`. See code below for how to do that.

Be aware that this way of accessing the information is a lot slower at runtime than directly specifying the properties in the source code.

```
using System.Reflection;

public class Items
{
    public ICollection<string> Items1 { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<int> Items2 { get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<bool> Items3 { get; set; } = [];

    public int NoCollection { get; set; }
    public bool NoCollectionEither { get; set; } 

    public int GetMaxCollectionCount()
    {
        // type of Generic ICollection interface used to identify properties
        var collectionType = typeof(ICollection<>);

        // Find all the properties that are of type ICollection<>
        var collectionPropertyInfos = 
            GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == collectionType);

        // For each property, get count, then get max value
        var maxCount = 
            collectionPropertyInfos
            .Select(GetCollectionCount)
            .Max();
        
        return maxCount;
    }

    private int GetCollectionCount(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        // Get the actual collection object from the propertyInfo
        var collectionObject = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);

        // Get the property info for the "Count" property of the collection
        var countProperty = collectionObject?.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(ICollection<object>.Count));
    
        // Get the actual Count value from the count PropertyInfo and the collection object
        var countObject = countProperty?.GetValue(collectionObject);

        return Convert.ToInt32(countObject);
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
var items = new Items()
{
    Items1 = ["A", "B"],
    Items2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    Items3 = [true, true, true]
};

Console.WriteLine(items.GetMaxCollectionCount());
```

Output would be `7`.